# Increase Spring Boot JMS message consumption rate

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I'm trying to identify how to increase the rate of message consumption of a JMS Springboot application. I tried testing the rate of message consumption of the app and it took 1.5 hrs to consume and process 2000 waiting/pending messages in QUEUE.

In other words, problem is, it took 1.5hrs for the springboot app to empty the QUEUE it's consuming from.

```
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private MyMessageService messageService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        String messageContent = null;
        try {
            if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
                long length = bytesMessage.getBodyLength();
                byte[] content = new byte[(int) length];
                bytesMessage.readBytes(content);
                messageContent = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } else if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                messageContent = textMessage.getText();
            }

            if (messageContent != null) {
                FileIOHelper.writeInboundXmlToFile(messageContent); //write message to file
                String accountNumber = XmlUtil.extractAccountNumber(messageContent);
                final String xmlMessageTransformed = messageService.transformXmlMessageToOldSchema(messageContent);
                if (!xmlMessageTransformed.isEmpty()) {
                    FileIOHelper.writeTransformedXmlToFile(accountNumber, xmlMessageTransformed); //write message to file
                    Map<String, String> outboundHeaderProperties = messageService.createJMSHeaderProperties(message);
                    messageService.publishMessageToOutboundTopic(xmlMessageTransformed, outboundHeaderProperties);
                } else {
                    FileIOHelper.writeUnprocessedXmlToFile(messageContent); //write message to file
                    log.error(
                            String.format("Failed transformation of message account# ", accountNumber));
                }
                message.acknowledge(); // acknowledge ALL inbound messages from inbound QUEUE
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, part of the processing of message involves writing a copy of inbound and outbound messages received to a file. I suspect this is what's causing the slow consumption/processing rate of messages from QUEUE.

In my JMS Configuration class, I have the following :

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(MessageListenerAdapter messageListener,
            @Qualifier("sourceConnection") ConnectionFactory listenerConnectionFactory) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(listenerConnectionFactory);
        container.setDestinationName(jmsSourceQueue);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
        container.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        container.setRecoveryInterval(30000); //reconnect every 30 seconds if disconnected.
        // container.setConcurrentConsumers(1); // do I need to add this line?
        // container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5); //Or, add this line?
        return container;
    }
```

I searched SO and learned about `setConcurrentConsumers()` and `setMaxConcurrentConsumers()` I'm not sure if that's how I can solve the slow message consumption rate.

The requirement for our JMS application is to be able to consume messages in just a few minutes. In my example above, it took 1.5 hrs to consume all 2000 messages.

Can you suggest a way or approach to solve this without removing the write-to-file step?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) How did you configure `MyMessageService`? For outgoing messages it is important to cache JMS objects, see [JmsTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html). 2) When `sessionTransacted=true`, acknowledge mode is ignored.

Comment: Before proceeding with modifications to your application you should profile it so you know _exactly_ where time is being taken. Otherwise your modifications may not make any difference at all. You may not actually gain any performance at all by increasing message consumption concurrency.